# Performing Node Searches in API's

Tags: html, r, json

Consider the following Reddit Post: https://www.reddit.com/r/datascience/comments/xlvr0l/who_is_applying_to_all_these_data_scientist_jobs/

**Part 1:** Here is an example of comments that were left on this post - Using the Reddit API ("Pushshift"), for a given comment on this post (e.g. a comment left by "Playful_Message_7944"), **I would like to retrieve all comments in the conversation, i.e. ALL previous comments in the conversation BEFORE "Playful_Message_7944" replied, and ALL future comments in the conversation AFTER "Playful_Message_7944" replied.**

[image]

**Part 2:**

- Based on the document for the API (https://github.com/pushshift/api) know that the following query can be used to find out this comment left by "Playful_Message_7944": https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/comment/search?limit=250&q=*&link_id=xlvr0l
- Then, I can identify the exact link (using ctrl+f and searching for the comment text): https://reddit.com/r/datascience/comments/xlvr0l/who_is_applying_to_all_these_data_scientist_jobs/ipln78n/

**Part 3:** We can now see the JSON information for this comment:

```
 {
            "all_awardings": [],
            "archived": false,
            "associated_award": null,
            "author": "Playful_Message_7944",
            "author_flair_background_color": null,
            "author_flair_css_class": null,
            "author_flair_richtext": [],
            "author_flair_template_id": null,
            "author_flair_text": null,
            "author_flair_text_color": null,
            "author_flair_type": "text",
            "author_fullname": "t2_eu0saeom",
            "author_patreon_flair": false,
            "author_premium": false,
            "body": "The 6 month certs people are LITERALLY boot campers. The boot camps pay to license the name of the schools so they can provide these \u201ccertificates\u201d",
            "body_sha1": "6a6cf7368516e1583d9a6e4978b3b002c77e37bb",
            "can_gild": true,
            "collapsed": false,
            "collapsed_because_crowd_control": null,
            "collapsed_reason": null,
            "collapsed_reason_code": null,
            "comment_type": null,
            "controversiality": 0,
            "created_utc": 1663943705,
            "distinguished": null,
            "gilded": 0,
            "gildings": {},
            "id": "ipln78n",
            "is_submitter": false,
            "link_id": "t3_xlvr0l",
            "locked": false,
            "no_follow": true,
            "parent_id": "t1_ipljm3d",
            "permalink": "/r/datascience/comments/xlvr0l/who_is_applying_to_all_these_data_scientist_jobs/ipln78n/",
            "retrieved_utc": 1663943724,
            "score": 1,
            "score_hidden": true,
            "send_replies": true,
            "stickied": false,
            "subreddit": "datascience",
            "subreddit_id": "t5_2sptq",
            "subreddit_name_prefixed": "r/datascience",
            "subreddit_type": "public",
            "top_awarded_type": null,
            "total_awards_received": 0,
            "treatment_tags": [],
            "unrepliable_reason": null
        },
```

**Part 4:** So far, I am able to partially retrieve comments that came after this "Playful_Message_7944" with the following code: https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/comment/?parent_id=ipln78n

**QUESTION:** But is there a way to retrieve all comments in the specific conversation that come before and after "Playful_Message_7944"'s comment?

To me this seems like a "Node Search" - for a specific comment, I want to retrieve all comments that are connected to this comment, all comments that are connected to comments that are connected to the original comment, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to get all the comments related to the post "Who is applying to all these data scientist jobs?" with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)

rd <- rsDriver(chromever = "105.0.5195.52", browser = "chrome", port = 4480L) 
remDr <- rd$client
remDr$open()
url <- "https://www.reddit.com/r/datascience/comments/xlvr0l/who_is_applying_to_all_these_data_scientist_jobs/"
remDr$navigate(url)

web_Obj <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]")
text <- web_Obj$getElementText()[[1]]
strsplit(text, "\n")[[1]][1 : 90]

[1] "350"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  [2] "publiée par"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  [3] "u/Alex_Strgzr"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  [4] "il y a 9 jours"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  [5] "Who is applying to all these data scientist jobs?"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  [6] "Job Search"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  [7] "I see all these job postings on LinkedIn with 100+ applicants. I’m really skeptical that there are that many data science graduates out there. Is there really an avalanche of graduates out there, or are there a lot of under-qualified applicants? At a minimum, being a data scientist requires the following:"
  [8] "Strong Python skills – but let’s face it, coding is hard, even with an idiot-proof language like Python. There’s also a difference between writing import tree from sklearn and actually knowing how to write maintainable, OOP code with unit tests, good use of design patterns etc."                            
  [9] "Statistics – tricky as hell."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 [10] "SQL – also not as easy as it looks."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 [11] "Very likely, other IT competencies, like version control, CI/CD, big data, security…"                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 [12] "Is it realistic to expect that someone with a 3 month bootcamp can actually be a professional data scientist? Companies expect at least a bachelor in DS/CS/Stats, and often an MSc."                                                                                                                              
 [13] "279 Commentaires"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [14] "Partager"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [15] "Sauvegarder"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 [16] "Cacher"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 [17] "Signaler"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [18] "87 upvotes"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [19] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [20] "commentaire"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 [21] "Trier Par: Meilleures"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 [22] "niveau 1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [23] "Arutunian"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 [24] "·"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [25] "il y a 9 j"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [26] "My understanding is that LinkedIn considers you to have “applied” if you click the “apply on company website” button, whether or not you actually submitted an application."                                                                                                                                       
 [27] "387"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 [28] "Répondre"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [29] "Partager"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [30] "niveau 2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [31] "azevedro"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [32] "·"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [33] "il y a 8 j"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [34] "That explains how you can have 1 day posted and 200 applicants my god"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 [35] "33"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 [36] "Répondre"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [37] "Partager"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [38] "Continuer ce fil"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [39] " niveau 2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 [40] "Alex_Strgzr"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 [41] "OP"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 [42] "·"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [43] "il y a 8 j"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [44] "Yeah, some companies have such a long and tedious application form that it wouldn’t surprise if some candidates gave up. Still, for the companies with Easy Apply where we know there are that many applicants, there are a lot of applicants for such a technical, hard-to-fill role."                            
 [45] "101"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 [46] "Répondre"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [47] "Partager"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [48] "Continuer ce fil"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [49] " niveau 2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 [50] "Muggleish_wizadry"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [51] "·"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [52] "il y a 9 j"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [53] "Really?! I didn't know this. Why would LinkedIn make such an assumption though?"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 [54] "Shouldn't be there a \"check\" on such things? Sometimes, it's just sad to apply for a job after one day of posting, seeing 89 people have already applied. Just happened to me an hour ago. :-("                                                                                                                  
 [55] "17"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 [56] "Répondre"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [57] "Partager"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [58] "Continuer ce fil"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [59] " niveau 1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 [60] "jjthejetblame"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 [61] "·"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [62] "il y a 8 j"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [63] "Well we hosted an internship this summer, 2300 applicants for one data science internship. We also hired a full time head in February, 250 applicants for one position. So I don’t think it’s simply how LinkedIn counts “apply” like some others have said here.. we really see this many applicants per job."    
 [64] "126"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 [65] "Répondre"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [66] "Partager"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [67] "niveau 2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [68] "Voth98"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 [69] "·"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [70] "il y a 8 j"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [71] "Out of those applicant pools, what percentage were reasonably qualified for the job?"                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 [72] "28"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 [73] "Répondre"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [74] "Partager"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [75] "Continuer ce fil"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [76] " niveau 2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 [77] "crunchytech413"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 [78] "·"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [79] "il y a 8 j"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [80] "Yeeesh. I feel bad for these people who are doing data science undergrad degrees now. It’s gonna be rough out there."                                                                                                                                                                                              
 [81] "27"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 [82] "Répondre"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [83] "Partager"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [84] "Continuer ce fil"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [85] " niveau 2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 [86] "Jooylo"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 [87] "·"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [88] "il y a 8 j"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [89] "·"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [90] "a modifié il y a 8 j"
```

Also, I tried it on another reddit link and it works :

```
url <- "https://www.reddit.com/r/datascience/comments/xr62ru/what_are_your_flexible_working_hours/"
remDr$navigate(url)

web_Obj <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]")
text <- web_Obj$getElementText()[[1]]
```

So, I think you can just navigate to the page that contains the post you are looking for and use the approach that I propose. It seems all the reddit pages have the same structure. This is the reason the xpath "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]" is working on two different pages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I know how to get all comments on a specific page - I am trying to get all replies to a specific comment ... and all the replies before that comment....do you know how to do this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can consider something like :

```
library(RSelenium)

rd <- rsDriver(chromever = "105.0.5195.52", browser = "chrome", port = 4480L) 
remDr <- rd$client
remDr$open()
url <- "https://www.reddit.com/r/datascience/comments/xlvr0l/who_is_applying_to_all_these_data_scientist_jobs/"
remDr$navigate(url)

list_Text <- list()

for(i in 1 : 100)
{
  print(i)
  xpath <- paste0("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[", i, "]/div/div/div/div[2]")
  web_Obj_Temp <- remDr$findElement("xpath", xpath)
  list_Text[[i]] <- web_Obj_Temp$getElementText()
}

list_Text[1 : 10]
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "niveau 1\nArutunian\n·\nil y a 9 j\nMy understanding is that LinkedIn considers you to have “applied” if you click the “apply on company website” button, whether or not you actually submitted an application.\n387\nRépondre\nPartager"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "niveau 2\nazevedro\n·\nil y a 9 j\nThat explains how you can have 1 day posted and 200 applicants my god\n31\nRépondre\nPartager"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] ""


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] "niveau 2\nAlex_Strgzr\nOP\n·\nil y a 9 j\nYeah, some companies have such a long and tedious application form that it wouldn’t surprise if some candidates gave up. Still, for the companies with Easy Apply where we know there are that many applicants, there are a lot of applicants for such a technical, hard-to-fill role.\n103\nRépondre\nPartager"


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] ""


[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[1] "niveau 2\nMuggleish_wizadry\n·\nil y a 9 j\nReally?! I didn't know this. Why would LinkedIn make such an assumption though?\nShouldn't be there a \"check\" on such things? Sometimes, it's just sad to apply for a job after one day of posting, seeing 89 people have already applied. Just happened to me an hour ago. :-(\n17\nRépondre\nPartager"


[[7]]
[[7]][[1]]
[1] ""


[[8]]
[[8]][[1]]
[1] "niveau 1\njjthejetblame\n·\nil y a 9 j\nWell we hosted an internship this summer, 2300 applicants for one data science internship. We also hired a full time head in February, 250 applicants for one position. So I don’t think it’s simply how LinkedIn counts “apply” like some others have said here.. we really see this many applicants per job.\n128\nRépondre\nPartager"


[[9]]
[[9]][[1]]
[1] "niveau 2\nVoth98\n·\nil y a 9 j\nOut of those applicant pools, what percentage were reasonably qualified for the job?\n30\nRépondre\nPartager"


[[10]]
[[10]][[1]]
[1] ""


> list_Text[1 : 20]
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "niveau 1\nArutunian\n·\nil y a 9 j\nMy understanding is that LinkedIn considers you to have “applied” if you click the “apply on company website” button, whether or not you actually submitted an application.\n387\nRépondre\nPartager"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "niveau 2\nazevedro\n·\nil y a 9 j\nThat explains how you can have 1 day posted and 200 applicants my god\n31\nRépondre\nPartager"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] ""


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] "niveau 2\nAlex_Strgzr\nOP\n·\nil y a 9 j\nYeah, some companies have such a long and tedious application form that it wouldn’t surprise if some candidates gave up. Still, for the companies with Easy Apply where we know there are that many applicants, there are a lot of applicants for such a technical, hard-to-fill role.\n103\nRépondre\nPartager"


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] ""


[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[1] "niveau 2\nMuggleish_wizadry\n·\nil y a 9 j\nReally?! I didn't know this. Why would LinkedIn make such an assumption though?\nShouldn't be there a \"check\" on such things? Sometimes, it's just sad to apply for a job after one day of posting, seeing 89 people have already applied. Just happened to me an hour ago. :-(\n17\nRépondre\nPartager"


[[7]]
[[7]][[1]]
[1] ""


[[8]]
[[8]][[1]]
[1] "niveau 1\njjthejetblame\n·\nil y a 9 j\nWell we hosted an internship this summer, 2300 applicants for one data science internship. We also hired a full time head in February, 250 applicants for one position. So I don’t think it’s simply how LinkedIn counts “apply” like some others have said here.. we really see this many applicants per job.\n128\nRépondre\nPartager"


[[9]]
[[9]][[1]]
[1] "niveau 2\nVoth98\n·\nil y a 9 j\nOut of those applicant pools, what percentage were reasonably qualified for the job?\n30\nRépondre\nPartager"


[[10]]
[[10]][[1]]
[1] ""


[[11]]
[[11]][[1]]
[1] "niveau 2\ncrunchytech413\n·\nil y a 8 j\nYeeesh. I feel bad for these people who are doing data science undergrad degrees now. It’s gonna be rough out there.\n27\nRépondre\nPartager"


[[12]]
[[12]][[1]]
[1] ""


[[13]]
[[13]][[1]]
[1] "niveau 2\nJooylo\n·\nil y a 8 j\n·\na modifié il y a 8 j\nIt is crazy. A ton of undergraduate schools started data science majors a few years ago and there is an astronomical number of people trying to get in. Not to mention all the bootcamps and people trying to transfer from other fields. I got lucky to get in years ago when I did.\n1\nRépondre\nPartager"


[[14]]
[[14]][[1]]
[1] ""


[[15]]
[[15]][[1]]
[1] "niveau 1\nits_a_gibibyte\n·\nil y a 9 j\nMaintainable, OOP code with unit tests and good design patterns?\nI've met about 3 people in my life that write genuinely high quality code. Everyone else's code (including my own) is an embarrassing mess of spaghetti.\n270\nRépondre\nPartager"


[[16]]
[[16]][[1]]
[1] "niveau 2\nlambo630\n·\nil y a 9 j\nYeah also, what is the task? Am I exploring data and trying to throw some models at it? If so, why do I need immaculate code with unit tests?\n78\nRépondre\nPartager"


[[17]]
[[17]][[1]]
[1] ""


[[18]]
[[18]][[1]]
[1] "niveau 2\nkaumaron\n·\nil y a 9 j\nI'd argue that OOP code is unnecessary most of the time and that's as a data engineer\n28\nRépondre\nPartager"


[[19]]
[[19]][[1]]
[1] ""


[[20]]
[[20]][[1]]
[1] "niveau 2\nSeven_Irons\n·\nil y a 8 j\nI'd even argue that maintainable code is unnecessary for a large number of data projects. So much data work is just based upon coming to good conclusions for some set of data, and presenting that data in a clear fashion.\nAll you need for that is some commented code that's repeatable so anyone can double check calculations at a later date.\nThe analysis may vary so much from project to project, based upon the data itself, that maintainable code might be putting the cart before the horse, so to speak.\n10\nRépondre\nPartager"
```

At the beginning of each paragraphs, you have "niveau 1" ("niveau 1" in french means "level 1" in english), "niveau 2", etc. With this, you can identify all the "subposts" that belong to a "post". All the subposts that are of "niveau 2" belong to the previous post of "niveau 1".

The code will loop over all the post / subposts of the page using the xpath.

Once you have the structure of all the conversations, you can extract the specific conversation you need by searching for the specific text.